# Oracle Hierarchical Query Get all Childrens All Level

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in which I have columns DataID and ParentID , so for one parent root I can have childrens and those childrens can have more childrens and so on
Structure something like this

```
Root
 Child1
    A
    B
 Child2
    C
    D
```

Can I use a hierarchical query to gather root and all its children no matter how deep the level is

Comment: Yes, that's what hierarchical means. (I guess there's some theoretical limit on level based on its datatype, but not something that's likely to ever trouble you). What do you mean by 'gather' though? What output do you want to see exactly, in what format?

Comment: I mean the output should have Root its children and grand childrens and so forth, can I get a sample query for this

Comment: Yes, you can. You can find examples of such queries under this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking for a very simple hierarchical query, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm), show in its [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#SQLRF52335), and many other places.

If you want the output you showed in the question, then you could do something like:

```
select lpad(' ', level - 1, ' ') || dataid as hierarchy
from your_table
start with parentid is null
connect by prior dataid = parentid;

HIERARCHY                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root                                                                            
 Child1                                                                         
  A                                                                             
  B                                                                             
 Child2                                                                         
  C                                                                             
  D
```

The `lpad` used the query level to indent the values by an appropriate number of spaces.